# How can I create a ListView of videos, and images?

Tags: java, android, listview

How can I create a ListView of videos?

I explain myself a little better, I want to make an app with a listview that contains short videos.

I create an activity list_item where I want to put images and text. For example in the first list item I want you to put a thumbnail and a description, for example: horse accident and in the second list_item put another thumbnail with another description, for example: squirrel attack.

I know how to create a list view that shows the same image in all the list_items, but I don't know how to make a list view that contains different videos, images and text for each list_item.

The images, the video and are stored in the assets and raw folder, respectively.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this library for videos using `ListView` :

**`implementation 'cn.jzvd:jiaozivideoplayer:6.2.12'`**

use this link for documentation : https://github.com/lipangit/JiaoZiVideoPlayer